# Regardless of fragment testing passing or failing I still get a FileNotFoundException when the fragment test starts from launchFragmentInCountainer

Tags: android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I'm testing Navigation and `launchFragmentInContainer()` is causing a `FileNotFoundException`. This is the stack trace:

```
E/System: Unable to open zip file: /data/user/0/com.sxhardha.ikonsdriver/cache/7tIiGc5E.jar
E/System: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File doesn't exist: /data/user/0/com.sxhardha
.
.
.
.
at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(FragmentScenario.java:282)
at com.sxhardha.ikonsdriver.navigation_test.RegisterFragmentTest.setUp(RegisterFragmentTest.kt:48)
```

And the line which is causing it is this:

```
val loginFragmentScenario =
            launchFragmentInContainer<RegisterFragment>()
```

What's going on? How can I fix this? Must note that this error occurs regardless of the test passing or failing.

The dependencies I'm using:

```
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.0-rc03'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.0-rc03'
    debugImplementation'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.2.0-rc03'
```

**Edit**
There is also an issue in the issue tracker in Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146054844

Comment: Happening to me as well, on multiple devices. Test runs on the device but this error fails the test always. Only difference is I use `fragment-testing:1.2.0-rc04`

Comment: I reported it as a bug in the issue tracker. You may follow it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146054844

Comment: Please share if you found any solution

Comment: Not yet. But you may type your issue in the issue tracker also. Or with the stacktrace, or you can just comment +1